# Creating a project in android studio . it downloads some files every time

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I create a new project in android studio. It downloads some files every time. It is really frustrating to wait for more than 15 minutes to complete. It is worse when the downloading got failed and ask to download it again.

I googled it and found a lot of ways Some people suggest this way. Some suggest that way but they all are confusing.
Is there any simple way so that the AS doesn`t need online every time to download files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable Gradle offline mode, It will fix your problem.

Follow this instruction on how to do that.
I'm assuming that you are using Android Studio on Windows.

**File** -> **Settings** -> **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Gradle**
Check the checkbox for **Offline work**. -> **Apply** or **OK**

**Update**

Go to the right side of Android Studio look for Gradle select it.
Then press the Toggle offline mode button.

[image]

You can check the effect by creating a new project.

Comment: What is your Android Studio version?

Comment: i am using latest version of AS which is 4.2 Beta 6

Comment: I think you mean shift button

Comment: I wonder why they would do this online thing. does gradle require a lot of performance or storage to run? and if yes why is google offering this performance for free? I have never seen anything like this before .